# Derivative of $\sec\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x\right)$ at $x=\pi/4$

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I was presented with the following excersice: Calculate the derivative of the following function and evaluate it at $x=\pi/4$

$\sec\left(\frac{3\pi}{2} - x\right)$

I used two different approaches and I was hoping for both to obtain the same results. Nevertheless this was not the case. Please find below my approaches

Approach 1:
Using directly the quotient rule and substitute for x, meaning the following:

> Step 1):
> Since we know that sec(x) = $\frac{1}{cos(x)}$, then we can apply the quotient rule directly and obtain the following: $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$

> Step 2)
> Substitute for x --> $\left(\frac{3\pi}{2} - x\right) \rightarrow \left(\frac{3\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$
> = $\frac{5\pi}{4}$

> Step 3)
> Solve --> $\frac{\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)}{\cos^2\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)}$ = $-\sqrt{2}$

Approach 2:
Using the chain rule: When using the chain rule the result is the following:

> $\sqrt{2}$

From what I have heard the right approach should be using the chain rule (approach 2)

Now since I do this more for the sake of learning instead of passing an exam or similar I would like to understand:

> 1-Why in this case the approach 1 is not suitable? (Otherwise I would have got the same results, right? Unless there is another kind of error, e.g.: alegebraic error or similar)

> My assumption is that I am overseeing something when it comes to my conceptual understanding.

Comment: You have a composite function. The derivative of $(3\pi/2-x)$ is $-1$

Comment: Yes, indeed and I know that. I was just experimenting around and triying another approaches. In this particular case I thought if I directly use  the quotient rule I might obtain the same results as when using the chain rule. This was not the case and now I am just wondering what is the logical explanation for that. You now what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach No. 1 was false from the very beginnning since the composite function was ignored and thus both approaches are not equivalent.

Let $f(x)=\frac{3\pi}2-x.$
$$\begin{align}(\sec\circ f)'&=(\sec'\circ f)~f'\\&=-\sec'\circ f\\&\ne\sec'\circ f.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand this correctly, the approach No. 1 was false from the very beginnning since the composit function was ignored and thus both approaches are not equivalent. Or could you please elaborate more on your explanantion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this particular simple case, it is useful to think that tho composite function has the effect of changing the direction of the $x$ axis (and shifting the origin, but that is not important for this problem). So if you look at the same point from two directions, a positive slope in one case will look like a negative slope in the opposite one.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}{rl}\text{Your first attempt:}\\\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d \sec((3\pi/2)-x)}{\mathrm d x}\right\vert_{x:=\pi/4}&\color{blue}{\neq}~\left.\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d \sec(y)}{\mathrm d y}\right\rvert_{y:=(3\pi/2)-x}\right\rvert_{x:=\pi/4}&\color{red}{\large\mathcal X}\\&=\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d \sec(y)}{\mathrm d y}\right\rvert_{y:=5\pi/4}\\[2ex]\text{Your second attempt:}\\\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d \sec((3\pi/2)-x)}{\mathrm d x}\right\vert_{x:=\pi/4}&=\left.\left(\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d \sec(y)}{\mathrm d y}\right\vert_{y=(3\pi/2)-x}\dfrac{\mathrm d~(3\pi/2)-x}{\mathrm d x}\right)\right\vert_{x:=\pi/4}&\color{green}{\large\checkmark}\\&=-\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d \sec(y)}{\mathrm d y}\right\rvert_{y:=5\pi/4}\end{array}$

> 1-Why in this case the approach 1 is not suitable? (Otherwise I would have got the same results, right? Unless there is another kind of error, e.g.: alegebraic error or similar)

You substituted into the derivand *before* you performed the differentiation. This would allow you to differentiate everything to 1:

$$\begin{align}\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d (x^3+x)^2}{\mathrm d x}\right\vert_{x:=2}&\neq\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d x^2}{\mathrm d x}\right\vert_{x:=2^3+2}\\&\neq\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d x}\right\vert_{x:=(2^3+2)^2} \\&= 1\end{align}$$

So do not do that.  Apply the Chain Rule:

$$\begin{align}\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d (x^3+x)^2}{\mathrm d x}\right\vert_{x:=2}&=\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d y^2}{\mathrm d y}\right\vert_{y=2^3+2}\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d x^3+x}{\mathrm d x}\right\vert_{x:=2}\\&=2(2^3+2)\cdot(3(2)+1)\\&=140\end{align}$$